# How to compare the content of local and remote directory via R

Tags: r, directory, compare, remote-server

I would compare a local list of csv files with another remote list of csv file on online server. I would use R for this, how I can do ?

I'm alreday connect via R to the online server and now I would like to compare the local folder with the online without download the online

Comment: Look into the `list.files` function in base R, which can list the files in both directories without downloading them. Other than that this question does not provide enough specific information to provide more detailed help.

Comment: Between `list.dirs`, `list.files` and `%in%` or `intersect` you should be set up

Comment: additionally, you can use  `setdiff(local_files, remote_files)` and/or `setdiff(remote_files, local_files)`